# Invalidated object not currently part of this pool

Tags: spring-data-redis

When I use redisCacheManager to put something, it throws an exception "Invalidated object not currently part of this pool". But when I set the usePool to false, it can work. I think this is a Multi-threaded case. But I don't know why the spring-data-redis's annotation can work.

```
<code>
 ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");
        UserServiceImpl userService = applicationContext.getBean(UserServiceImpl.class);
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = applicationContext.getBean(RedisCacheManager.class);
        redisCacheManager.getCache("cacheName").put("key","value");

    <cache:annotation-driven ></cache:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
          p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
        <property name="usePool" value="true"></property>
        <property name="hostName" value="${redis.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${redis.port}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
          c:template-ref="redisTemplate"/>
</code>
```

Comment: i solve it by update version.